SwiftData error on iOS 18, Never access a full future backing data
Try to update my app from iOS 17 to iOS 18. I'm using SwiftData to save the data on the memory. On iOS 17 all works fine, but I tried to export my app to iOS 18, and I get a strange error when I try to delete a playlist from SwiftData memory.
Thread 10: Fatal error: Never access a full future backing data - PersistentIdentifier(id: SwiftData.PersistentIdentifier.ID(url: x-coredata://4885953A-BDB2-4CD1-9299-B2FBBB899EB7/PlaylistItem/p372), implementation: SwiftData.PersistentIdentifierImplementation) with Optional(B2A80504-2FE1-4C86-8341-3DDE8B6AB913)


The code where this error happen is very simple,
  func deletePlaylist(_ playlist: PlayListModel) async throws {
        print("attempt to delate :, \(playlist.playlistName)")
        context.delete(playlist)
        try context.save() // error here on the save 
    }


Error only happen on iOS 18 not on the 17.

I'm encountering this too. The behaviour of the crash changes depending on the relationships (mine are one to many) that exist in the deleted model but whatever I've tried, the crash persists. Can you show the PlayListModel?

Note that the error is for PlaylistItem and not the PlayListModel that is shown in the code, I assume they are related? If you run this with Core Data debug logging do you see anything interesting in the logs?

I had the error too, no iCloud, iOS 18 beta 2.
What fixed it for me is deleting all relationships and saving the context before I delete the parent.
for parent in parentsToDelete {
    for child in parent.childs {
        context.delete(child)
    }
    try context.save()
    context.delete(parent)
}
try context.save()


Just add the following in your @Relationship when deleting a model like so:
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var routineItems: [RoutineItem] = []


This error occurs in various scenarios, but I found a solution for my case.
My scenario: After logging in, I sync data from the server. Once the sync is complete, the data is inserted into SwiftData. Then, I log out, which removes all data from the local database. After logging in again, the app syncs data, but during this process, the app crashes with the error: 'Never access a full future backing data.'
   let myCommunityPageController = PageController<CommunityDetails>()

   func syncCommunity() async {

        myCommunityPageController.isDone = false
        myCommunityPageController.dataList = [] // After adding this error fixed.

        // Here, I am making an API call and inserting data into myCommunityPageController.dataList. The API call itself is not shown in this code snippet.

        if myCommunityPageController.isDone {
            await addCommunity(myCommunityPageController.dataList)
            userData.communitySynced = true
            Envi.shared.saveChanges()
        }
    }

    func addCommunity(_ communityDetails: [CommunityDetails]) {
        for community in communityDetails {
            let inbox = getCommunityInbox(community.recipientId)
            modelContext.insert(inbox)
            try? modelContext.save()
            
            inbox.communityDetails = community // Error came here "Never access a full future backing data"
            try? modelContext.save()
            
            inbox.communityDetails?.membersList = community.membersList
            try? modelContext.save()
        }
    }

Solution: After inserting data into SwiftData from the array (or any object), clear the array to prevent inserting the same reference again. If you attempt to insert the same reference again, it will cause this error.
In my case, I fixed the error by clearing the old reference from the array.
    myCommunityPageController.isDone = false
    myCommunityPageController.dataList = []

I hope this helps someone.
